# Variable Scope issue with if statements (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement, scope

Alright I seem to have a misconception with variable scope with PHP, forgive my lack of the subject as I come from a Java, C# background.  Thinking I could make variables accessible to functions or if statements simply by placing it outside it.  Below is a snippet of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
foreach ($nm as $row=>$im) {
    $itm_name = $im;
    $lnk = $lnk_cty[$row];  
    if($mode == 'addMenu') {
        $m = $m_id; //id will be coming from fresh insert of menu_name 
    } else {
        $m = $_POST['mnu_add'][$row];
        echo "MENU_ID: ".$m;
    }
    if($mode == 'addCat') {
        $m = $c_id; //id will be coming from fresh insert of cat_name
    } else {
 $m = $_POST['cat_add'][$row];
    }
    //used for testing purposes
    echo "item name: ".$itm_name ."<br />";
    echo "lnk: ".$lnk ."<br />";
    echo "m: ".$m ."<br />"; //$m is empty here, because its a new declaration as oppose to accessing $m value from if statement
    $display_fields .= "<li>".$itm_name." ".$item."</li>";
    $sql_array[] = '("' . $itm_name . '", "' . $lnk . '",  ' . $m . ')';  // Add a new entry to the queue 
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is make the `$m` variable values accessible outside the if statements its in to the `$m` variable used in the `$sql_array[]` statement.  In C# I would simply declare a variable outside the foreach loop and be able to use it. After doing some reading on the matter I found that using the global or GLOBALS keywords would only work if my global scope variable is assign the value before the foreach, and declaring `global $m` to obtain that value within the loop.  But with my current code `$m` is of a local scope within the if statements and everyone discourages using them. Now, is there a better method of making `$m` accessible to the `$sql_array[]` statement?

Comment: what does it mean: 'id *will be* coming?'

Comment: The source of the ID would be ...

Comment: @Aurel300 thank you mr. Translator. Could you please tell the actual $m_id value in the runtime?

Answer (score 76):

`If` statement blocks do not have their own scope. Whatever data you are assigning to `$m` must be empty to begin with.  Try debugging things like your `$_POST` variables.  Also, where is `$m_id` being defined?  Maybe it is empty as well.

PHP **does** have scope inside functions, class methods and the like.  But `if` statements do not have their own scope.  For example, the following code would echo `Hi there!`:

```
$bool = true;
if ($bool) {
    $new_var = 'Hi there!';
}
echo $new_var;
```

Have a read in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: @Stephen, $m_id is coming from a resultset from a mysql table.  When testing it with the echo statements in the code it shows the value for  $m when assigned that id and from the resultset and also when assigning the $_POST variable to it in the else block.  Here is a snippet:  

$results = statement("select menu_id from `$menu` where menu_name = '$menu_nm'");
while ($recordset = mysql_fetch_array($results))
      {
      if($mode == 'addCat'){
       $c_id  = $recordset['cat_id'];
      }else{
       $m_id = $recordset['menu_id'];
      }
      }

Comment: One of these is empty: `$m_id`, `$_POST['mnu_add'][$row]`, `$c_id`, or `$_POST['cat_add'][$row]`