# PHP, var is not defined

Tags: php

i really dont get why this var is not being defined.

```
if(isset($_POST['test']))
{
    $directory = 'C:/Users/Oscar/Documents/test/';
    $files = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));


    foreach($files as $file):?>

    <table border="2px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" name="file" />    
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php endforeach;


}
if(isset($_POST['file']))
{   
    //print_r($_POST['file']);
    echo file_get_contents($directory.$_POST['file']);
}
```

the directory var is not being defined, im calling it on the last "if". dont know why

Comment: If `$_POST['test']` is not set, `$directory` is never initialised.

Comment: `$directory` only gets initialized if $_POST['test'] exists. If it doesn't, that code branch never runs, and the var never gets set

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, script for reading files in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212769/php-script-for-reading-files-in-browser)

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to

```
$directory = 'C:/Users/Oscar/Documents/test/';
if(isset($_POST['test']))
{
    $files = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
   .....
```

I hope you understand what is happening here. You conditionals are basically (in terms of the actual logic not code) if{}else if{}

Moving the var which is shared out of the first conditional block ensures that it is available in both blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Because the if statement is false.

Put $directory = 'C:/Users/Oscar/Documents/test/'; above this line: if(isset($_POST['test']))

Comment: You should really elaborate on your answer. This is more of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

So $post['test'] returns false and $directory is then undefined.

Comment: `if` statement blocks do not have their own scope in php. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4110430/1967396